# I have almost succeeded in putting latex fonts into R graphs, but it's slightly off

Tags: r, latex

I am learning latex graphics. I generated latex graphs with standalone, but I am trying to generate R plots with latex fonts. Through online tutorials, here is my code with the `Iris` dataset in RStudio (I modified example code to get it working. Once I know how to fix the frame, I can study the code in more details):

```
library(tikzDevice)
options(tikzMetricPackages = c("\\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}",
                               "\\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}", "\\usetikzlibrary{calc}",
                               "\\usepackage{amssymb}"))
## I need the amssymb package because I use \mathcal and \mathbb
tikz("formula.tex", width = 4, height = 4, standAlone = TRUE,
     packages = c("\\usepackage{tikz}",
                  "\\usepackage[active,tightpage,psfixbb]{preview}",
                  "\\PreviewEnvironment{pgfpicture}",
                  "\\setlength\\PreviewBorder{0pt}",
                  "\\usepackage{amssymb}"))
par(mar = c(4, 4, 0.1, 0.1), mgp = c(2, 0.9, 0))
library(tikzDevice)
options(tikzMetricPackages = c("\\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}",
                               "\\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}", "\\usetikzlibrary{calc}",
                               "\\usepackage{amssymb}"))
## I need the amssymb package because I use \mathcal and \mathbb
tikz("formula.tex", width = 4, height = 4, standAlone = TRUE,
     packages = c("\\usepackage{tikz}",
                  "\\usepackage[active,tightpage,psfixbb]{preview}",
                  "\\PreviewEnvironment{pgfpicture}",
                  "\\setlength\\PreviewBorder{0pt}",
                  "\\usepackage{amssymb}"))
par(mar = c(4, 4, 0.1, 0.1), mgp = c(2, 0.9, 0))
plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width, main="Iris sepal length vs width measurements", xlab="Length", ylab="Width")

dev.off()

tools::texi2pdf("formula.tex")
system(paste(getOption("pdfviewer"), "formula.pdf"))
```

Which gives me:

[image]

I would like to have a bit more white space on the right, so the 8 comes fully, and fix the title. The inner picture should be smaller and the title lower as well, if possible.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for this. I looked at the code and figured it out! I needed to remove

```
par(mar = c(4, 4, 0.1, 0.1), mgp = c(2, 0.9, 0))
```

which gives me:

[image]

So it works!!! :D